# Infinispan cache table - timestamp-column is always -1

Tags: java, wildfly, infinispan

I am using WildFly25 with Infinispan.

I have the following cache configured:

```
    <distributed-cache name="corpapp-session-cache-web">
      <persistence>
        <string-keyed-jdbc-store>
          <data-source jndi-url="java:/jdbc/sessioncache" data-source="SessionCacheDS" dialect="POSTGRES" passivation="false" preload="false" purge="false" shared="true"/>
          <string-keyed-table drop-on-exit="false" create-on-start="false" prefix="session">
            <id-column name="ID" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
            <data-column name="DATA" type="BYTEA"/>
            <timestamp-column name="VERSION" type="BIGINT"/>
            <segment-column name="S" type="INT"/>
          </string-keyed-table>
        </string-keyed-jdbc-store>
      </persistence>
    </distributed-cache>
  </cache-container>
```

When I start the application, it writes successfully to the table, however the value in the timestamp column (`VERSION`) is always `-1`.

[image]

I would expect it to be a timestamp or even a version number that increments.

This results in the next time I start up the Wildfly server, it tries to create a previously created index again:

**Error**

> *ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address:
> ([("deployment" => "corporateEAR-3.10.ear")]) - failure description:
> {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" =>
> {"org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.web."corporateEAR-3.10.ear.corporateInterface-3.10.war""
> => "org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManager
> Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component
> org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManager
> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.infinispan.persistence.spi.PersistenceException:
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation
> "session_corporateEAR_3_10_ear_corporateInterface_3_10_war_times"
> already exists
> Caused by: org.infinispan.persistence.spi.PersistenceException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation
> "session_corporateEAR_3_10_ear_corporateInterface_3_10_war_times"
> already exists
> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "session_corporateEAR_3_10_ear_corporateInterface_3_10_war_times"
> already exists"}}*

**Question**

How can I configure it to generate the table correctly?  So it doesn't try re-create the index when the server reboots resulting in the above error stopping the application being deployed to WildFly.

The server can start up and deploy the application successfully the first time. However, when the generated table  exists, on restarting the server it can't deploy the app because of the above error.

Note that the table name and index names are long, so the index  names are truncated.

**More info**

The generated table has two indexes called:

```
session_corporateEAR_3_10_ear_corporateInterface_3_10_war_times
session_corporateEAR_3_10_ear_corporateInterface_3_10_war_segment
```

More info

Even though I don't access the application, and it leaves the cached table empty, on  the next restart of the server it gets the same error. So this suggests that the problem is not the `-1`.  It looks like it is trying to create the index that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

change type of timestamp column to timestamp type or varchar(255) whichever work.

also deployment fails becuase "ERROR: relation "session_corporateEAR_3_10_ear_corporateInterface_3_10_war_times" already exists" there already existing relation with this name. also ive noticed that hibernate try to create table with name "session_corporateEAR_3_10_ear_corporateInterface_3_10_war_timestamp..something" but it is not possible with Postgres to have that much longer name please make use of shorter table name.

Comment: I cannot change the timestamp column to anything other than BIGINT otherwise it gets a classCastException trying to cast a BIGINT into that type.

Comment: it is possible to change the table names prefix, but I am not sure if it is possible to change the tables name.  I will investigate.

Comment: i doesn't look like it is possible to change the name of the generated table, as you can see here that attribute doesn't exist in the schema. https://infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-cachestore-jdbc-config-7.2.xsd. I can possibly change archive names inn their respective pom.xml files.